# Best practices when copying source files with Docker

Tags: python, docker

Lastly, I have been trying to improve my Docker skills, but there is something I'm still stuck when I have to deal with it. Let's say I have an application divided into modules, each of them being its own Docker service.

All modules use the config stored under config/config.ini, but this config needs some preprocessing so what they use is the functions of config/config.py.

I have implemented that as:

- Each Dockerfile of each module COPY the contents of the config/ folder into their own (`COPY ./config .`)
- Each module imports the config functions with: `from config import ###`

This method does work, but it breaks the IDE as the config folder is not on the pythonpath so I lost some important functionality, and what is worse I don't think this is the cleanest way of achieving what I want.

Furthermore, this also happens with source files. Normally in my python development, I would have just created a package called "APP" (see the folder structure below) and then I could have imported any source file in any folder of the package, but because each subfolder is a different Docker service I cannot make this project a python package. For example, the tests are also dockerized so each test also copies the needed source files from other folders:

the file `unit_test_main_module.py` needs to test all the source files in `main_module` so it copies the files with the Dockerfile.

```
APP
 ├── unit_tests
     ├── Dockerfile
     └── unit_test_main_module.py
 ├── integration_tests
     ├── Dockerfile
     └── first_integration_test.py
 ├── config
     ├── config.ini
     └── config.py
 └── main_module
     ├── source_file_one.py
     └── source_file_two.py
```

Any advice?

Comment: Can't you append the PYTHONPATH with the folder for config in IDE?

Comment: Another option is to use the same folder structure inside the docker image as well

Comment: Appending to PYTHONPATH is what I have been doing. Using the same structure for the docker image will still yield some errors like "attempted relative import beyond top-level package" as the whole APP is not a package

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having one Dockerfile per *process*. A Docker image is basically a self-contained way to run a process. So if you only ever run one process, you only need one Dockerfile.

You might want, perhaps, a second Dockerfile for a testing image. But you don't need one per package.

Assuming two, one for main application and one for tests, it would be in top directory.

Comment: my way of seeing it is having a dockerfile per service. That is, one for the module that controls the API, one for the module that loads some data, one for the DB, etc... is that wrong? That way if a service crashes it can restart automatically without affecting the rest of the services

Comment: If you're actually creating your application as a distributed application, with multiple processes, then the Docker packaging is correct. However, distributed programming is very difficult to get right: instead of a function call, you know have an RPC call that might timeout. You're much better off starting with a single process.